# Non-cryptographic encryption algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, hash

Similar to a non-cryptographic one-way hash (eg, for building hash tables) I find myself needing a not-necessarily-cryptographic-strength two-way, symmetric-key "encryption" function.  My plan is to use it in the design of a data structure.

Desired properties are:

- Fast
- Not terribly difficult to implement (in Java if it matters)
- Need not even be totally reversible; if given the plaintext size if it generates a small, expected-constant number of possibilities, that would be OK.
- Deals well with small data sizes (eg, "encrypting" a single 64-bit long)
- Good bit dispersion characteristics (ie, XOR-with-random-number is suboptimal because sequential numbers will end up with most bits shared).  Relation to number of bits set in the input and output should be ~random.

Does such an algorithm exist, or can something in the Java standard library be shoehorned into that role?

Comment: Why not just use a real one like AES? Especially with that last requirement.

Comment: My suspicion is that something like AES, even with processor support, is massively overkill (read: slower than it needs to be) for these purposes.  Eg, plenty of non-cryptographic hash functions disperse bits well.  I'm also just curious about whether this is a defined class of algorithms.

Comment: what must be size of output ?

Comment: @Bryce Perhaps a reduced-round variant of a standard encryption algorithm, then? 5-round AES128, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to take an easily implementable cipher like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29 and run it with a reduced number of rounds - e.g. from 16 to 3. 3 - because 3 rounds are used in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher#Theoretical_work.

Another would be to use h(x) = a * x + b mod p (or mod 2^n if a is odd). For p prime this is an example of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing if x is limited to (0, p-1). Where x is in fact a number of words long, you could process each word individually - not secure at all, but then security is not your aim. Whether it is random enough or not depends on your data and what you are trying to achieve by hashing it.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a reduced-rounds version of a standard block cipher is the way to go.